# Adding SAML insertion in Mulesoft Anypoint Studio

Tags: esb, saml

We're using Mulesoft's ESB technology with Anypoint Studio.  I've never used either before but have been tasked with adding SAML insertion into our existing Anypoint flow.  I've looked online and found...

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/SAML+Module

And a very few others like this.  Problem is that these are assuming that you aren't using Anypoint Studio, I think.  They at least assume that you know which files to manually edit.  Is there a tutorial or something for doing this through Anypoint Studio for Mulesoft?  Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually isn't too difficult but we got tripped up on a couple of snags.  Inside our service we defined the cxf:ws-sercurity tags.  Note that if you leave the "Signature" off of the "SAMLTokenSigned Signature" that the it doesn't work.  We ran into that problem.

```
<cxf:proxy-service namespace="https://example.com/services/Mobile/LinkDevice" 
    service="Mobile_LinkDevice_Service" payload="envelope" 
    wsdlLocation="http://wsdl.example.com/services/Mobile/LinkDevice/service.php?wsdl" 
    enableMuleSoapHeaders="false" doc:name="LinkDevice">
  <cxf:ws-security>
    <cxf:ws-config>
      <cxf:property key="action" value="SAMLTokenSigned Signature"/>
      <cxf:property key="signaturePropFile" value="wssecurity.properties"/>
    </cxf:ws-config>
  </cxf:ws-security>
</cxf:proxy-service>
```

Our wssecurity.properties file looks like this and it sin our resources folder.

```
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider=org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type=JKS
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password=zlg23tkoi71ugvl9
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias=sbg
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.file=/home/mule/conf/saml.jks
```

At the top of our Mule config file we defined the keystore and the username/password combo for it.  Our second major issue we ran into here was the keystore.  When we created this on our dev machine and tested, it worked fine.  When we copied everything over to the Staging environment, Mule could no longer access the keystore.  We fixed this by generating the keystore on the Staging environment and not simply copying it over.  Once it was created there, it worked fine.

```
<https:connector name="httpsConnector" clientSoTimeout="0" serverSoTimeout="0">
  <https:tls-key-store path="${mule.home}/conf/keystore.jks"  storePassword="curd-of-milk"
    keyPassword="cheese"/>
</https:connector>
```

The only other thing to really watch out for is making sure your soap request has everything it needs in the SAML header.  I'm not going to go into all that other than to say I found it to be a pain in the ass.